# NextJS API routes on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

Apologies if this is a dumb question but where are the API routes in a next JS application deployed to AWS Amplify hosted?

I know that Amplify supports backends, but generally I'm explicitly writing an express server or something. Since the next JS routes are serverless, does that mean that Amplify is deploying them as lambda functions behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, Amplify deploys them as Lambda@Edge functions. [Source](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/blob/main/FAQ.md#access-lambda-edge-logs).